# React helmet or next/head for Next Js project?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-helmet

I am making a next js application (React SSR), and now I am into implementing the meta tags in head.

So for now I have used [**next/head**](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/head) in _app.tsx file like,

```
import React from 'react';
import App from 'next/app';
import Head from 'next/head';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import theme from '../src/theme';

export default class MyApp extends App {
  componentDidMount() {
    // Remove the server-side injected CSS.
    const jssStyles = document.querySelector('#jss-server-side');
    if (jssStyles) {
      jssStyles.parentElement!.removeChild(jssStyles);
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Head>
          <title>My page</title>
          <meta name="viewport" content="minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, width=device-width" />
        </Head>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          {/* CssBaseline kickstart an elegant, consistent, and simple baseline to build upon. */}
          <CssBaseline />
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </ThemeProvider>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

And the whole working code can be found here at sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-tereshkova-217ks

I am just to know whether using `next/head` itself enough in next js application or else need to implement [**react-helmet**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet) ??

If the `react-helmet` is needed then kindly help me how to implement in the provided next js application.

I am new into Next Js and SSR, So please help me in right direction which is the best method to achieve the result.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> I am just to know whether using next/head itself enough in next js application or else need to implement react-helmet ??

react-helmet makes sense to use if you're rolling your own server side rendering solution and are not using Next.js. As far as I know, `next/head` is bascially a built-in version of react-helmet and does everything react-helmet does.

**So no, you don't need to use react-helmet if you are using Next.js. Just use `next/head`.**

> If the react-helmet is needed then kindly help me how to implement in the provided next js application.

That said, if you want to use react-helmet with Next.js, here is an example: https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-react-helmet. Not sure why you'd do this, but the example exists. There is [some discussion](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/pull/1264#issuecomment-282266855) about it.

By the way, just like react-helmet, you can use `next/head` anywhere in your render tree—not just the `App` component like in your example—and all the tags will be aggregated into the `<head>` tag at the top.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and I would like to know whether to use ```react-helmet``` or ```next/head``` and based on your input I could confirm that ```next/head``` itself enough while using next js.. Am I right??

Comment: @TestUser yep. I haven't come across a single use-case where `next/head` is insufficient. Just add things to `<Head>` anywhere in your tree, and `next/head` will aggregate them into the page `<head>`. No need for `react-helmet`.

Comment: I added **bold** to the short version of my answer :).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. It helps to understand that react-helmet is not needed in ```next/head``` ..

Comment: Also do you have any idea of adobe analytics implementation in next js project?? For which I already have a question https://stackoverflow.com/q/60376041/12856847 but none of the answer helps..

Comment: I’ve never used Adobe Analytics but based on the answer by Tessaracter it looks very similar to Google Analytics and I bet his/her answer is on the right track, if not even entirely correct.

Comment: Do you have any idea here?? https://stackoverflow.com/q/61080276/12856847

Comment: Nope, sorry! Not sure about that one.

Comment: One thing react-helmet can do that next/head cannot is add classes to the <html> tag and the <body> tag (i.e., `<Helmet><html lang="en" /><body class="root" /></Helmet>`) within each page component. This can be useful if you want to add classes to body tag based on current page. Next.js provides a custom Document (`pages/_document.js/tsx`) to add classes to <html> and <body> tags, which is different that the react-helmet approach.

Answer (score 3):

There is also a great package for Meta tags for Next JS
[next-seo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-seo)

Comment: it uses next/head underhood